# Render variables from a file

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, jinja2, render

There is a file api.yml containing a config for ansible:

```
config/application.properties:
 server.port: 6081
 system.default.lang: rus
 api.pdd.url: "http://{{ stage['PDD'] }}"
 api.policy.alias: "integration"
 api.order.url: "http://{{ stage['Order'] }}
 api.foo.url: "http://{{ stage['FOO'] }}
```

There is a stage.yml containing the key and the stage values:

```
default_node:
 Order: '172.16.100.40:8811'
 PDD: '172.16.100.41:8090'
 FOO: '10.100.0.11:3165
```

In fact, these files are larger and the 'stage' variables are also many.
My task is to parse api.yml and turn it into properties-config. The problem is that I can not pull up the values ​​{{stage ['value']}} I'm trying to do it this way:

```
stream = yaml.load(open('api.yml'))
result={}
result.update(stream['config/application.properties'])
context= yaml.load(open('stage.yml'))
stage={}
stage.update(context['default_node'])
text = '{% for items in result | dictsort(true)%}  {{ items[0] }} = {{
     items[1] }} {%endfor%}'

template = Template(text)
properti = (template.render(result=result, stage=stage))
```

At the output I get this:

```
server.port = 6081
system.default.lang = rus
api.pdd.url = http://{{ stage['PDD'] }}
api.policy.alias = integration
api.order.url = http://{{ stage['Order'] }}
api.foo.url = http://{{ stage['FOO'] }}
```

And you need to get this:

```
server.port = 6081
system.default.lang = rus
api.pdd.url = 172.16.100.41:8090
api.policy.alias = "integration"
api.order.url = 172.16.100.40:8811
api.foo.url = 10.100.0.11:3165
```

Can I do it with jinja or ansible lib?
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You have a lot of python in your question, but at the end you ask about jinja2; is your question about python or ansible, because the answer will change dramatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this approach, you would need to treat `api.yml` as a template itself and render it. Otherwise, jinja2 will treat it as a simple value of the property. Something like this would do:

```
import yaml
from jinja2 import Environment, Template 
import json  


stream = yaml.load(open('api.yml'))
result={}
result.update(stream['config/application.properties'])
context= yaml.load(open('stage.yml'))
stage={}
stage.update(context['default_node'])
text = """{% for items in result | dictsort(true)%}  {{ items[0] }} = {{ items[1] }} {%endfor%}"""

#Then render the results dic as well
resultsTemplate = Template(json.dumps(result))
resultsRendered = json.loads( resultsTemplate.render(stage=stage) )

template = Template(text) 
properti = (template.render(result=resultsRendered, stage=stage))
```

After this you will see the wanted values in the `properti` var:

```
'  api.foo.url = http://10.100.0.11:3165   api.order.url = http://172.16.100.40:8811   api.pdd.url = http://172.16.100.41:8090   api.policy.alias = integration   server.port = 6081   system.default.lang = rus'
```

It would be nice though if jinja2 was able to render recursively. Maybe spending some time working out with the globals and shared modes of the [Environment](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Environment) this can be achieved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much is just what you need